# Hyperledger REST Server has PUT method vs Blockchain Immutability

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Why does Hyperledger REST Server has PUT method to update participants/assets? 
Isn't blockchain main feature its immutability?
Is it okay for us to update/change an entitiy of participant/asset?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with the PUT method you don't change anythin. In a Blockchain never is deleted a data. With the PUT you add a new registry.